# Haskell Monad State: gets and modify

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad

I'm confused with the definitions of  gets and modify in monad state.

---

[Somewhere](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html) says:

gets:  "Gets specific component of the state, using a projection function supplied".

modify: Maps an old state to a new state inside a state monad. The old state is thrown away.

That means we can use modify to directly assign a value to a component of state, like [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_StateT_use).

---

But [somewhere](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) else says we can supply a function to state and result using modify and gets.

---

It seems both works, but it's not clear to me which one works where!

Comment: I can't understand what is the source of your confusion. `gets` takes the state and applies a user-provided projection function. `modify` alters the state with a user-provided function mapping the old state to the new one. What is the problem here? You should edit your question and make it clearer.

Comment: If you are going to quote from external sources, please actually quote them. For the 2nd source, the word "apply" doesn't even appear on the page. What does that page actually *say* that causes you confusion? (as opposed to stating what you've understood from it that causes you confusion). `modify` changes the state, `gets` retrieves it. If you want to change the state, you can use `modify`. If you want to retrieve it, you can use `gets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never quoted from the second citation so I'll ignore it in this answer. If you clarify that part of the question then I'll try to answer it.

Your cited source one says:

```
gets :: MonadState s m => (s -> a) -> m a Source #
Gets specific component of the state, using a projection function supplied.
```

and

```
modify :: MonadState s m => (s -> s) -> m () Source #
Monadic state transformer.
Maps an old state to a new state inside a state monad.
```

So for `gets` you can supply a function `s -> a` and it will return the `a` after applying that function  to the current state.  For `modify` you supply a function `s -> s` and the new state is the result of your function applied to the old state.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I modified the question. I'm after a simple example that allows a series of functions to modify a global state. Something, in principle,  like the 3rd example on the following,  that example does not change the state using some functions: https://wiki.haskell.org/Simple_StateT_use